# Download complete website via CLI

Tags: html, performance, web

I'm trying to reduce the size of my website, but to do that I need a reliable tool to measure the size of my pages.

- I used to use Google Lighthouse, in the performance audits it reports the size, but it's not precise, and it's inconsistent with the network tab
- I tried several combinations of curl, but I can't make it crawl website correctly
- I tried several combinations of wget, but it couldn't handle correctly the gzip or brotli encoding
- I came to the conclusion that wget or curl are not the right tools, because they don't evaluate JS, so they can't do conditional loading of assets
- I'm trying now with puppetter.js and phanotm.js, but I still haven't managed to do it

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: What's the discrepancy between Lighthouse and Network tab?

Comment: one of the two is not precise, there's a lot of rounding error, which, for multiple files, can add up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Measure Size**

Web browsers make a lot of decisions about what to download based on their particular context (for example, what compression algorithms it supports). It's difficult to replicate those conditions in an external tool, such as curl. So you'll want to use a tool that thinks like a browser (or is a browser).

The server can also choose to send different content based on visitor information (user agent, whether they're logged in, geolocation, etc.) or even completely arbitrary conditions (like a randomized image). So you'll want to look at more than one sample, preferably from many user agents and locations.

Most tools don't provide that kind of power.

The closest thing I can suggest is [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/). It uses an actual web browser to visit your site and reports an analysis of that visit, including total page weight (even broken down by different page events). WebPageTest can be used as an API and even run locally. Output is available as JSON, so you can parse and do custom reporting with CLI apps.

**How to Speed Up a Website**

The technical question of "weighing" a website aside, there's a broader problem you're trying to tackle: how to speed up your website. There is a *lot* of information available for performance optimization.

Specifically, there's a lot of discussion about what metrics should be considered when evaluating a page's performance, how much weight should be given each metric, and how to use that information to prioritize optimizations.

When considering page weight, I would highly recommend breaking it down by how many bytes are necessary to accomplish certain tasks. Google recommends thinking about resources in terms of the [critical rendering path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/) - the HTML, blocking JS, and non-deferred CSS necessary to construct a web page.

You may have a 1MB page where render-critical assets only make up 10KB of the page - that's a very fast site. Or you may have a 1MB page where 500KB are required for an initial render - not so fast. WebPageTest helps break down those weights by event for you.

I wish I could give more technical detail about using WebPageTest with CLI tools. It's something I plan to explore soon. But for now, hopefully this will give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) ?
Analyze you website and read on optimization guidelines.